# Property of $F_{m,n}$ distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X \sim F_{n,m}$ and I want to show that $X^{-1} \sim F_{m,n}$, where $F_{m,n}$ is the $F$ distribution with $m$ and $n$ degrees of freedom. I had two methods of showing this which I tried; one where I got stuck, and the other seemed too simple.

Starting with the simple method, I want to verify correctness and inquire if my reasoning is flawed.

> Let $X \sim F_{n,m}$. Then $X = \frac{U/n}{V/m}$, where $U$ and $V$ are independent $\chi^2$ random variables with $n$ and $m$ degrees of freedom respectively. By taking the inverse of $X$ we get that
>   $$X = \frac{U/n}{V/m} \iff X^{-1} = \frac{V/m}{U/n}$$
>   and by definition $X^{-1}$ has the $F$ distribution with $m$ and $n$ degrees of freedom so $X^{-1} \sim F_{m,n}$.

For my other method, I want to know if I am taking a valid approach, and if so could I be hinted in a direction toward the next step?

> Let $X \sim F_{n,m}$ and let $Y = X^{-1}$. 
>   \begin{align}
> P(Y < y) & =
> P(X^{-1} < y) \\ & =
> P(X \geq 1/y) \\ & = 
> 1 - P(X < 1/y) \\ & =
> 1 - \frac{\Gamma[(n+m)/2]}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(m/2)}
> \Big(\frac{n}{m}\Big)^{n/2}
> \Big(\frac{1}{y}\Big)^{n/2-1}
> \Big(1+\frac{n}{my}\Big)^{-(n+m)/2}
> \end{align}

From here I wasn't quite sure how I should attempt to algebraically manipulate the formula to make the density function match.

Comment: In your second approach, in the last equality you use the density function ($f_X(1/y)$). However, you want the cdf (since $P(X<1/y)=F_X(1/y)$). Or you can go from $F_Y(y)=1-F_X(1/y)$ to the pdf by doing $f_Y(y)=d/dy[1-F_X(1/y)]$.

Comment: The first approach is charming in its simplicity, but _don't use it_. Operations on the _function_ defining a random variable, do not generally map unchanged in the probability density function (which is a function that describes properties of the range of a random variable, not the function that defines the rv itself). Standard example: the density of the _sum_ of two independent rv's is the _product_ of their densities (not their sum). The 2nd approach has the mistake mentioned by @hejseb. Use change-of-variable formula, and post the answer -if you're stuck let me know and I will post it.